# user can't connect remotely to mysql on ubuntu server

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, ubuntu-server

I have a mysql database running remotely on an ubuntu server.  I've created two users on the mysql database.  the privileges they have are below.  with user1 I am able to login in remotely with mysql workbench and query the database, but with user2 I am not.  if I ssh in to the server, then I am able to login and query the database with user2.  does anyone see what the issue might be and can you suggest a solution?

code:

```
mysql> show grants for 'user2'@'0.0.0.0';
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for user2@0.0.0.0                                                  |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'user2'@'0.0.0.0'                                   |
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `stocks`.* TO 'user2'@'0.0.0.0' WITH GRANT OPTION |
|GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `sandbox`.* TO 'user2'@'0.0.0.0' WITH GRANT OPTION|
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> show grants for 'user1'@'0.0.0.0'
    -> ;
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for user1@0.0.0.0                                                   |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'user1'@'0.0.0.0'                                    |
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `sandbox`.* TO 'user1'@'0.0.0.0' WITH GRANT OPTION |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

update:

checking firewall on ubuntu server

```
sudo ufw status
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere                  
3306                       ALLOW       Anywhere                  
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
3306 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

also I commented out "bind-address" in /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf and restarted mysql.

still I can't connect remotely with user2 but user1 still connects just fine from mysqlworkbench.  I can login to mysql with user2 when ssh in to the server.

Comment: The code example is definitely irrelevant. Most likely a network issue and belongs to ServerFault. Are you sure Workbench doesn't connect via an SSH tunnel? That's an option there...

Comment: @marekful I do not believe so.  also I've connected from multiple computers using mysql workbench and the user1 login.

Comment: @marekful I've added updates to my original post regarding the server firewall and the mysql mysqld.cnf file.  the firewall should be open to all ip for mysql and likewise for mysql in it's config.  is there something I'm missing, or do you know where else I should check?